# Could not create a new page layout in sharepoint online site(E3 trial) using Design manager

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, design-manager

I created an e3 trial sharepoint site.I was creating pagelayouts using design manager but Im getting error like **sorry, u dont have access**  though I created the tenant site and I am site coll. admin still im facing the Access issue.
Can anyone help me in this.
[image]

Comment: Check if this helps you: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/enable-custom-script-in-sharepoint-online

Comment: This does not helped me.Still I face same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if you have the permission to access the Master Page Gallery.

If you do not enable the custom scripts in the site, then you cannot create the create or edit master pages and page layouts. For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Allow or prevent custom script.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script)

Since we have enabled custom scripts inside the "SharePoint admin center", then it will take up to 24 hours until the timer job runs to turn on the custom scripting.

And the custom scripts tenant-wide applies to SharePoint MySites, Personal OneDrive sites and Any SharePoint site collection created based on self-service site creation.

And you also could use the PowerShell below to enable the custom script in the site immediately.

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

More reference:

[Enable custom script on modern SharePoint sites to recover your favourite functionalities.](http://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2018/10/28/enable-custom-script-on-modern-sharepoint-sites-using-powershell/)